# Facebook Sharing with new facebook sdk 3.5 android

Tags: android, facebook, session

what I need to do is to allow my facebook application to share data on user wall but without asking the user of his credentials but using the session that he is already open in his installed facebook application, I have searched a lot and I didn't find anything to help me, please anyone can help please

please you will find the example on that link

https://app.box.com/s/va06jtp1e6nqet6qbdjr

Comment: This is not possible. Your app MUST ask the user for permission.

Comment: OK what happen that when I open session for publish it open login page to enter username and password not the application authorization page, I want it to get user token from already installed application and then open the application authorization page to ask user for his permissions

Comment: also all the examples not working with old devices for example (2.3.6) it can't get any thing from already installed application

Comment: Please post some code on how you're trying to login via Facebook.

Comment: About comment #2 I will attach the code that I'm using on the question

Comment: About comment #4 all examples works fine when I update the facebook application of my device

Comment: Hi although the previous example is running with some problems, but when I have tried to integrate it with my application, the method getActiveSession() return null to me and I can't complete my sharing process, I know that the new application is very difficult and they helped us a lot, so any suggestions why Sharing doesn't come with application pronile